# created bundle option into existing bundle wont save programatically

Tags: save, bundle, option, create

Magento 2.4.2-p1

Goal is to create a bundle option with a selection in it based on array of skus.
The array has 4 skus of simples existing in the catalog, lets say:
[50702640,50702240,90102870,90102871]

The strange thing, is that it will never add the first one.
Logs i have put in:

module-bundle/Model/Option/SaveAction

module-bundle/Model/OptionRepository

module-bundle/Model/OptionManagement

shows its being saved and giving back an optionId:

saveAction save SAVED resource save option title: 1665148566 optionId: 908641

saveAction save SAVED resource save option title: 1665148566 optionId: 908642

saveAction save SAVED resource save option title: 1665148566 optionId: 908643

saveAction save SAVED resource save option title: 1665148566 optionId: 908644

BUT, db shows differently (908641 is missing):

mysql> SELECT * FROM catalog_product_bundle_option_value WHERE title REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';

| value_id | option_id | parent_product_id | store_id | title      | placeholder |

| 21012029 |    908642 |              5831 |        0 | 1665148566 | NULL        |

| 21012055 |    908643 |              5831 |        0 | 1665148566 | NULL        |

| 21012083 |    908644 |              5831 |        0 | 1665148566 | NULL        |

mysql> select * from catalog_product_bundle_option order by option_id DESC limit 20;

| option_id | parent_id | required | position | type   | category_id |

|    908644 |      5831 |        0 |        0 | radio  |        NULL |

|    908643 |      5831 |        0 |        0 | radio  |        NULL |

|    908642 |      5831 |        0 |        0 | radio  |        NULL |

I have tried changing order of skus with no result.
(as alternative, if i create only one option, and put the array of links in it and save that only option, it wont save)
All of this, without errors that i can find in logs (debug, syslog, system, exception, mysql)

And here the code in question:

```
    foreach ($newProductLinksSkus as $newLinkSku)
        {
            /** @var OptionInterface $option */
            $option = $this->optionInterfaceFactory->create();
            $option->setRequired(0)
                ->setType('radio')
                ->setTitle(strval($this->date->getTimestamp()))
                ->setOptionId(null)
                ->setSku($this->currentProduct->getSku());
            /** @var LinkInterface $link */
            $link = $this->linkFactory->create();
            $link->setSku($newLinkSku)
                ->setQty($incomingItemLinksSkusAndQty[$newLinkSku])
                ->setCanChangeQuantity(1);
            try {
                $option->setProductLinks([$link]);
                $optionid = $this->optionManagement->save($option);
                #$optionid = $this->productOptionRepository->save($this->currentProduct, $option);
            } catch (CouldNotSaveException|InputException $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($this->prefix . $fn . "save fail {$e->getMessage()}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this code in a clean magento install 2.4.5 CE and it works correctly, in case someone looks for a working code snippet.

So the problem should be debugged in our current customised version of the shop.